# Image upload via Ajax To draggable content?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, user-interface

I Am building a simple application with drag and drop functionality (a stickies board is good example) the users will post text stickies via Ajax, php.  Which loop back and be draggable stickies (done using jquery ui).

I did want to have image upload too.  but research has pointed to the fact this not possible with Ajax.  So any ideas? I have Heard about using iframe as a target for the post data (to fake Ajax).

I have seen it done, the site that gave the idea is www.stixy.com.   This what I am after in an ideal world.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, this is a great plugin that will make it easy for you to upload multipart form seamlessly.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

It will handle the creation of the iframe and everything else.

Comment: Cheers for the reply will check out! Been racking my brain all day about this! Stack overflow once again to the rescue!